# SVG error in my j2me NetBeans6.5 project

Tags: netbeans, java-me, svg, netbeans6.5

I use svgForms, svgMenus and svgSplashScreen, but one annoying error always appears in the pre verification (last) step, which is the following:

```
Error preverifying class org.w3c.dom.svg.SVGElement  
    java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3c/dom/Element
```

It seems like it needs a library to be added, but I have hit the wall here. My svg files are all of baseProfile='tiny'.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You need stubs for JSR226 on the preverifier class-path. The file is usually called jsr226_1.1.jar.

Once you specify what tools exaxtly are you using to build the application I could be able to help more.

Answer (score 0):

In your project properties, select "Platform", then look into the "Optional Packages" area.

From there, you can then select the SVG API to add the missing component.